# Core data random crash

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I finished the development of my app but at this point I face random crashes when I try to save an image in core data.

Here is the console message:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught
>   during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an
>   observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. 
>   -[_PFExternalReferenceData compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x94b69b0 with userInfo (null)

The problem is that it is non deterministic. It happens more or less once out of 5 times.

Would anyone have an idea where I should look for ?

EDIT:

Here is the code of my class that seems to pose a problem. It happens sometimes when I click on the save button, calling -(IBAction)saveResultingImage:

```
#import "ResultViewController.h"


@interface ResultViewController ()
@property (nonatomic)BOOL resultSaved;
@end

@implementation ResultViewController


#pragma mark - IBActions

- (IBAction)saveResultingImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    _resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    _resultSaved = [self saveOnCoreData];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BackToStartSegue" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)discardWithoutSaving
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BackToStartSegue" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)restartDrawing:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *backgroundImage = _subImage;
    UIImageView *imageView =
    [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height)];
    imageView.image = backgroundImage;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    UIImage *maskImage = _maskImage;
    CGRect maskViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height);
    ImageMaskView *subView = [[ImageMaskView alloc] initWithFrame:maskViewRect image:maskImage];

    [self.view addSubview:subView];
}

- (IBAction)showExplainVC
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowInfoSegue" sender:self];
}


#pragma mark - Methods

- (BOOL)saveOnCoreData
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newMeme =
            [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Meme" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSData *toSaveMeme = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_resultImage);
    [newMeme setValue:toSaveMeme forKey:@"image"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        DebugLog(@"Can't save: %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark - View Controller LifeCycle

- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"BackToStartSegue"]) {
        return _resultSaved;
    }
    return _resultSaved;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    DebugLog(@"Called viewWillAppear");
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *discardBarButtonItem =
            [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Discard" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(discardWithoutSaving)];
    UIBarButtonItem *saveBarButtonItem =
            [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(saveResultingImage)];
    UIBarButtonItem *infoBarButton =
            [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"How to" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showExplainVC)];
    discardBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[saveBarButtonItem, discardBarButtonItem, infoBarButton];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [self restartDrawing:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Core Data Stack

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

@end
```

Thanks for showing interest :-)

Comment: post your code.. So anyone can say, what to change and how better you can use them

Comment: Nobody's got any single idea where I should look? I'm still stuck with this problem, random crashes when saving...

Comment: just comment this line and run again your code.. `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BackToStartSegue" sender:self];` I think you are doing some perform in the `viewWillAppear` in your `viewController`. That may rise a problem. get back to me after tried that and find still some random crashes occur.

Comment: Hello, all I'm doing in viewWillAppear is to set the navigationBar to be visible (because it was set to invisible in the previous viewController) and to set it to black. I perfom the segue when I press on the save button, which is linked to -(IBAction)saveResultingImage, and then calls performSegue. I also call perform segue when I click on "Discard" button, to directly go to the first screen of my app. I commented both and played with my app. It crashed again the third time with this error message :

Comment: CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[_PFExternalReferenceData compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x94cfcf0 with userInfo (null)
2013-07-30 22:10:17.000 MemeGen[43615:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_PFExternalReferenceData compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x94cfcf0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c96012 0x18f1e7e 0x1d214bd ...

Comment: To explain the comportment of my app: there are three tabs. One where is the main action. You can pick an image from your library or from the camera. Then you can pick a lol text from a list. Then you can choose if the image or the text comes over and you have two images layers. You can erase parts of the first layer by drawing with your finger to create a meme. You can then save it in core data. I can follow exactly the same process, it sometimes crashes and sometimes not, be it in the simulator or on the phone it's the same comportment. I think the two other tabs of the app aren't relevant.

Comment: @Iweingart In the previous comment I mentioned about the viewWillAppear: method in the previous controller. Bcoz that will get called when you perform the segue. I don't know how to help you. But this is the error. Actually you are changing the objects in the managedObjectContext. But some viewController in the stack not get updated to the new changed objects. So when it is having reference of the changed object, it crashes. I hope you are using managedObjectContext in all the controllers. You should try to use the singleton managedObjectContext.

Comment: Oh, I didn't get to which viewWillAppear method you were refering to.  Indeed, I use manajedObjectContext in all controllers, but not a singleton. I will try to follow your advice. Thank you very much for your help and for your interest :-).

Comment: If you get any improvement, then post it and accept as answer. That will help others too.

Comment: Yes of course. But to tell you the truth, I finally avoided the problem by saving my images on the file system instead of the core data. I'll come back to try and find a solution to this problem when I get a little more time to spend on it. Sadly, I have to present this app quite soon. But I'm definitively interested in finding the solution, and I will try to follow your advice when the time comes. :-)